# Custom ListView Row, can no longer select rows

Tags: sproutcore

Here's my ScrollView:

```
 middle: SC.ScrollView.design({
  layout: { top: 36, bottom: 32, left: 0, right: 0 },
  backgroundColor: '#ccc',

  contentView: SC.ListView.design({
    contentBinding: 'Spanish.wordsController.arrangedObjects',
    selectionBinding: 'Spanish.wordsController.selection',
    contentValueKey: "word",
    contentDisplayProperties: 'word english'.w(),
    selectOnMouseDown: YES,

    exampleView: Spanish.CustomListItemView

  })
})
```

and here is my custom listView row:

```
Spanish.CustomListItemView = SC.View.extend({
  render: function(context, firstTime){
    var content = this.get('content');

    var word = content.get('word');
    var english = content.get('english');

    context = context.begin().push('&nbsp;%@ (%@)'.fmt(word,english)).end();
    return sc_super();
  }
});
```

The above works as expected, except that I can no longer select views. When I comment out "exampleView: Spanish.CustomListItemView" I can select rows, but they are no longer formatted properly. Why can I no longer select rows when I use exampleView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass SC.ListItemView instead.

Remove the `return sc_super();` line.

Change the `context = context.begin().push('&nbsp;%@ (%@)'.fmt(word,english)).end();` line to:

```
context.push('&nbsp;%@ (%@)'.fmt(word,english));
```

It should work now.

Comment: Works with your suggestion to subclass from SC.ListItemView

Answer (score 0):

After getting help on IRC, I made the following changes which fixed the problem:

```
Spanish.CustomListItemView = SC.ListItemView.extend({
  render: function(context, firstTime){
    var content = this.get('content');

    var word = content.get('word');
    var english = content.get('english');

    context.push('&nbsp;%@ (%@)'.fmt(word,english));
  }

});
```

I was subclassing the wrong class (note the first line)